# plotly.net chart not found

Tags: f#, plotly, f#-interactive

My code is below, i am running this on a chromebook (debian)in vs code.

The url the browser tries to load is file:///tmp/631a67c5-f214-4538-8f46-e74ea90ecb98.html

The browser does have access to the tmp directory and I load the list of files at file:///tmp/. It appears plotly doesn't put the file in the tmp directory.

What am i doing wrong?

```
#r "nuget: Plotly.NET, 2.0.0-preview.6" 

open Plotly.NET 

  
let x  = [1.; 2.; 3.; 4.; 5.; 6.; 7.; 8.; 9.; 10.; ]
let y = [2.; 1.5; 5.; 1.5; 3.; 2.5; 2.5; 1.5; 3.5; 1.]


let line1 =
    Chart.Line(
        x,y,
        Name="line",
        ShowMarkers=true,
        MarkerSymbol=StyleParam.Symbol.Square)    
    |> Chart.withLineStyle(Width=2.,Dash=StyleParam.DrawingStyle.Dot)
    

line1
|> Chart.Show;;
```

Comment: This works for me, I'm on Fedora.

Comment: What do you get when you execute `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()`? I think that's the directory that Plotly.NET uses. You could try to debug by implementing your own version of `Chart.Show`. The code [is quite simple](https://github.com/plotly/Plotly.NET/blob/bbacaa3bc55fcfe2bb5c8043d2d3d641bcae6fb6/src/Plotly.NET/ChartExtensions.fs#L1005).